# Get route from Modal component Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I am unable to access the route on modal component.

**Module**

```
//code inside module
const CALENDAR_ROUTES = [
 { path: 'calendar/:user', component: CalendarPage },
];
```

**First component** is `CalendarPage` where the second one `NewAppointmentWizardComponent`(modal component) is opened from:

```
//code inside CalendarPage component - shows how NewAppointmentWizardComponent is opened
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NewAppointmentWizardComponent, {size:'lg'});
```

Here on `CalendarPage` component I can easily access the route with:

```
//code inside CalendarPage component
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       console.log("params", params.user); //works fine here
});
```

**But on the Second component** `NewAppointmentWizardComponent` the same thing returns `undefined`.

```
//code inside NewAppointmentWizardComponent component
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       console.log("params", params.user); //is undefined
});
```

I know that only `CalendarPage` component is defined on the route but how can I access the route on `NewAppointmentWizardComponent` as well? 
I have tried countless resources with no luck. Am I missing something here?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can't you just pass the parameter to the modal component from the 'main component'?

Comment: I usually pass them from template and read it as an @input but this is not initialized from template, I am not sure how I can pass and access it from the code directly. Is there another way other than template way?

Comment: I don't know what your modalService is doing exactly, but you must have some reference to the component, probably `modalRef`? Then you could just pass the parameters that way

Comment: So you mean modalRef.a ="whatever" or modalRef.componentInstance.a on the first component and then accessing it as this.a on the second one? If so I have tried those as well and did not work unfortunately. Maybe I am accessing it wrong. Is "this.a" the correct way to access it inside ngOnInit?

Comment: The second component needs a public property `something`. Then you should be able to set `modalRef.something` or whatever your reference to your component is. Then, in the second component, your can access it via `this.something`. But as I said, I don't know what your modalService is doing exactly and how you components look like. Maybe you can create a small Plunker?

Comment: You deserve a beer, it seems to work. Thank you!